# Filter files with a extesion and run a command for all found files in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, solr

I want to find all the files having .zip extension in a folder (**MyFiles**) recursively and run the following command for each file in Windows PowerShell.

> PS C:\solr-7.3.0> java -Dc=myCore1 -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files
>   -Drecursive=yes -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar **"File fullpath goes here"**

Could you help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Get-ChildItem` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) to find the relevant Zip files and then pipe the results to the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) to loop over the files. The `$_` or `$psitem` variable is the current object passed through the pipeline. Then the `FullName` property on that object will contain the full path to each Zip file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Example\Path -Filter '*.zip' -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        & java -Dc=myCore1 -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar $_.Fullname
    }
```